# How can I generate tilings using a computer?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, tiling, python

I was reading this wikiperdia article on [polyminos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino#Tiling_regions_with_sets_of_polyominoes).

The pictures look very nice. Example

[image: Source: Wikipedia]
I want to learn how to generate these figures myself in an *interactive way*.

Basically I want to start with a polymino and then I want to be able to translate (by unit distance up-down or left-right) this polymino by pressing arrow keys and place it at the desired location. Then I want to pick another copy of the same polymino and place it at another desired location and so on.

Can somebody please help me get started as to where can I learn this?

Can I implement this is python?

Thank you.

PS: I had looked for a python stackexchange before posting here, but that particular site (yet) does not exist. I thought of a few other options but none seemed appropriate. I finally decided to post this question here (and I admit I should have looked for more stack sites better suited for this question). I have now posted it on game development stackexchange too: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/169727/writing-an-interactive-code-for-planar-tiling-in-python-if-possible

I apologize if my post does not belong at MSE. However, I do not want to delete this post since it has got 3 upvotes already (along with some hints suggesting that my judgement was in error). Of course, the ultimate decision rests with the moderators, which I will respect. Thank you.

Comment: I vaguely recall being told they even have a whole stackexchange site dedicated to all that computer stuff.